# Fundamental solution of a shifted operator

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, special-functions, harmonic-analysis

what is the fundamental solution of the shifted operator $ \Delta + \lambda^2 $, i.e, what the function $f$ satisfying the following equation
$$ (\Delta + \lambda^2 )f(x) = \delta(x),$$
where $ \Delta = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ and $\delta(x)$ is the dirac measure at $x=0$.

In our considered case, this amounts to prove that for any $g$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ the following identity holds
 \begin{equation}
 g(0)=\int_0^\infty(\Delta + \lambda^2 )f(x) \, g(x) d(x).
   \end{equation}

Someone can help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a severe problem in your question. If $f$ is a solution of the equation $\Delta+\lambda^2)f=\delta$, then $f(0)$ cannot be defined and the integral relation cannot be true. Did you mean to write $$g(0)=\int(\Delta+\lambda^2)f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx ?$$

Comment: @ Tom-Tom, yes that's what I would write, I modified the message, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to Fourier transform your equation, using
$$\hat{f}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ixy}dx$$
your equation becomes:
$$(-y^2+\lambda^2)\hat f(y)=1$$
So:
$$\hat f(y)=\frac{-1}{y²- \lambda²}$$
And you need to Fourier transform it back:
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ixy}}{y²- \lambda²}dy$$
To evaluate this, you can use the residue theorem with a semi-circular contour on the upper-half of the complex plane for $x>0$ and the lower-half for $x<0$. There are two poles at $y\pm \lambda$ with residue $\pm e^{\mp i\lambda x}/2\lambda$. Now you can set a contour which goes around the poles in different manners ; using a contour going below both poles, I get:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{\lambda}\theta(x)$$
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function. It works if I am not mistaken. This is more a physicist's answer than a mathematician's one though